# For loop in R to download map data (raster package)

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I'm currently trying to plot a map of Africa using the different countries and plotting them together. I use the following code to download and plot a single country, which works perfect:

```
CMR <- getData('GADM', country='CMR', level=0)
plot(CMR)
```

I wanted to do this now for all the different countries in Africa. So I've made a charactervector (charafr) containing all these GADM codes and now I want to try to save them all to a seperate vector using a for loop. I'm a bit puzzled on how to assign these to seperate vectors. This is what I have:

```
for (i in 1:53){
     africancountries[i] <- getData('GADM', country=charafr[i], level=0)
}
```

This doesn't work and I'm not 100% sure on how to adjust the formatting so all the spatialpolygondataframes will be in a different vector.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know where the data is to download it directly?

Comment: What package is `getData` from?

Comment: I'm sorry I should've provided that information, The getData function is from the package called raster, and GADM is a database of administrative boundaries.

Comment: Before the loop: `africancountries<-vector("list",length(charafr))`. Inside the loop: `africancountries[[i]] <- getData('GADM', country=charafr[i], level=0)` (note the double square brackets `[[`).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'd tried running it and it looked like it worked, however at this moment all the spatialpolygonsdataframes are now stored in a 'Large List', I'd like to get all the different vectors as seperate 'largepolygonsdataframes'. Sorry for my unclear explanation.

Comment: Not much clear. You can retrieve one of the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` through `africancountries[[i]]`, where `i` is the index you want. Each element of the list is a different object. This is what a `list` in `R` is. If that doesn't respond to your question, please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
library(raster)
charafr <- c('RWA', 'BDI', 'UGA')
```

With a for loop:

```
ac <- list()
for (i in 1:length(charafr)){
     ac[[i]] <- getData('GADM', country=charafr[i], level=0)
}
allac <- do.call("bind", ac)

plot(allac)
```

Or, with `lapply`, more concise, but less readable:

```
charafr <- c('RWA', 'BDI', 'UGA') 
allac2 <- do.call("bind", lapply(charafr, function(x)  getData('GADM', country=x, level=0)))
```

To save this to disk as a shapefile, you can do

```
shapefile(allac2, 'allac.shp')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the charafr vector so I'm not totally sure if this will function (I tested with a 2 element vector), but based on your comments above it should work. This will result in a single `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and it can be written out using `writeOGR` if you want a shapefile. Note this will function the same way as the list, in that if you want a specific country you need to call it using list syntax. However, it does have the spdf class.

```
uid <- 1

for ( i in 1:53 ) {

  africancountry <- getData( 'GADM', country=charafr[i], level=0 )

  n <- length( slot( africancountry, "polygons" ) )

  africancountry <- spChFIDs( obj = africancountry, x= as.character( uid:( uid+n-1 ) ) )

  uid <- uid + n

  if(i == 1){ africancountries <- africancountry } else { africancountries <- rbind( africancountries,africancountry ) }
}
```