# Download Multiple Country Shapefiles

Tags: r, lapply, do.call

I am trying to download multiple country shapefiles and bind them together using raster::getData, lapply, and do.call. I've used this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878807/for-loop-in-r-to-download-map-data-raster-package) before, but I'm now getting an error: "Error in getData("GADM", country = x, level = 0) : 
  unused arguments (country = x, level = 0)"

Here is my code:

```
library(raster)
misc = list()
misc$countries = c("ZAF", "LSO", "SWZ", "ZWE", "MOZ", "NAM", "BWA")
ctry_shps = do.call("bind", lapply(misc$countries, 
                                    function(x) getData('GADM', country=x, level=0)))
```

Any thoughts on why this doesn't work now and how to fix it?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Perhaps a conflict with other libraries in my environment? I tested it in my R console and it worked fine, as you said.

Comment: It now works in the larger environment I'm in, but I had to add "raster::getData" or it would throw the error stated above.